# html/php form to calculate a display result of a simple formula

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm need a HTML/php form on a webpage that solves the following formula, without refreshing the page. I'm struggling with how best to go about it and the code needed to accomplish the task.

The formula needed would be as follows:

```
100 / ((X * 2)+3) =Y
```

`X` being input into an input box by the user, or selected from a drop down.

`Y` being the result displayed, rounded down, with no decimal places, either worked out live upon input/selection or displayed upon a button press.

Is there anyone out there who can help me?

Comment: Convince us this isn't a homework problem. Or, at least, show us the work you've done to get partway there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While, there are plenty of people who *can* help you, but this site isn't really about finding someone to write code for you, but for finding someone to help you with problems you've run into writing your code. What have you tried? Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Blazemonger - I'm a 29 year old who's not been in education for 5 years, how's that?
@NathanielFord - I appreciate that and am well aware, I think you have me grossly missunderstood. I've asked for help, not for someone to write code for me.

Comment: I recommend you check out the link I provided. Your question boils down to "what code do I need to accomplish X?" I'm not trying to stonewall you here but it really is better if you take a stab at it and then we help you see what you're missing, rather than us laying out everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need PHP for this, plain javascript or jQuery will do.

I've created a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8u0orb3/1/) for you.

```
$('#btnCalc').click(function(e)
{
var num = $('#txtNo').val();
var result = Math.floor(100 / ((num * 2)+3));
$('#result').html('Value is ' + result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, not something I'd thought about to be honest, it's been so long since I've used Javascript in such a way it never entered my mind.

I'll go down this route.